# How to determine if a process in a docker container terminated gracefully?

Tags: docker

[`docker stop`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/) sends the `SIGTERM` signal to the main process of a container. If the main process does not terminate after a default timeout period of 10 seconds, then the `SIGKILL` signal is sent to forcefully terminate the process. `docker stop` always returns 0, however, regardless if the process was terminated gracefully or not. This example, for instance, shows that the command returns 0 even though the process (`sleep infinity`) was terminated forcefully (after 10 seconds of waiting):

```
[student@c7c ~]$ docker run -d --name test_container busybox sleep infinity
b52c8fce1d7aeb20782a0e2e5bf970911363632b84b1c01e6dbbb985440e8f8b
[student@c7c ~]$ docker stop test_container
test_container
[student@c7c ~]$ echo $?
0
```

My question is, how should I edit my command(s) to be able to stop a container and yet be able to determine if the process in the container was terminated gracefully or forcefully due to timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Exit Status](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#exit-status) from the [*docker inspect*](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/) command.

Use the following command:

```
docker inspect test_container --format='{{.State.ExitCode}}'
```

In case of graceful termination of the container, it will return `0` else a non-zero integer.